# Vector layer properties won't load in function call

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Using [Leaflet.VectorGrid](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) I load vector tiles on a leaflet map. I am trying to style the tiles based on the received tile value but the function options.vectorTileLayerStyles doesn't load. Code example:

```
function getColor(val) {
    return val > 85 ? '#2172ff':
           val >= 75 ? '#42baff':
           val >= 50 ? '#a8e8ff':
           val >= 25 ? '#ffcea8':
           val >= 1 ? '#fc9803':
                        '#fc0303';
}

var options = {
    interactive: true,
    maxNativeZoom: 15,
    fetchOptions: {
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + key }
    }
};

//Doesn't get used, althought it should based on the layer's constructor definition
options.vectorTileLayerStyles = function(properties){
    var val = properties.val;
    return {
        mountains: {
            radius: 1,
            weight: 1,
            fillOpacity: 1,
            fill: true,
            fillColor: getColor(val)
        }
    }
}

layer = L.vectorGrid.protobuf(url, options).addTo(leafletMap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`vectorTileLayerStyles` option](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html#vectorgrid-vectortilelayerstyles) must be an object, not a function:

> `vectorTileLayerStyles`   *Object*
> A data structure holding initial symbolizer definitions for the vector features.

But [individual layers in `vectorTileLayerStyles` can be styled by a function](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html#styling-vectorgrids):

> A layer style can be either:
>
> - A set of L.Path options
> - An array of sets of L.Path options
> - A function that returns a set of L.Path options
> - A function that returns an array of sets of L.Path options for point, line, and polygon styles respectively

Try passing an object defining a function for your `mountains` layer, something like

```
options.vectorTileLayerStyles = {
    mountains: function(properties) {
        var val = properties.val;
        return {
            radius: 1,
            weight: 1,
            fillOpacity: 1,
            fill: true,
            fillColor: getColor(val)
        };
    }
}
```